# Install PyGame to USB (Windows)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I've downloaded Python IDLE on a flash drive so that I can work on the computers at school where I cannot download anything due to not having admin privileges.

When trying to run the file "config.py" from the pygame-1.9.4 folder I installed from the official I get this:

```
Using WINDOWS configuration...


Backup existing "Setup" file [Y/n]:n
```

I entered in n- like the other few times I tried- and I got the same old message.

```
Path for SDL not found.
Too bad that is a requirement! Hand-fix the "Setup"
Path for FONT not found.
Path for IMAGE not found.
Path for MIXER not found.
Path for PNG not found.
Path for JPEG not found.
Path for PORTMIDI not found.
Path for COPYLIB_tiff not found.
Path for COPYLIB_z not found.
Path for COPYLIB_vorbis not found.
Path for COPYLIB_ogg not found.

If you get compiler errors during install, doublecheck
the compiler flags in the "Setup" file.
```

I've tried running the config.py file as well as the setup.py file, nothing seems to work. I would love to install from pip but the whole idea of storing it on a USB drive doesn't allow the luxury of the command prompt knowing what the heck I'm saying when I type, "python -m pip install pygame".

Any help on this would be great. Perhaps it cannot find the right resources/files it needs because I am storing it on a flash drive, but overall I don't have much of a good idea. I've looked on other posts on Stack Overflow but they haven't worked, probably due to the fact that the situation is different from running on a dedicated hard drive where everything is in one place. Again, any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Download them at home then put the module folders in the same folder as your program